# Android Studio: I accidentally deleted my app.iml file from my project, how do I add it

Tags: android-studio

Now, my project will not run...it is telling me that my app module is missing.  Has anyone had this problem before?  I have no idea what information was in that file, so I dont know what to do.  Any recommendations would be appreciated :-)

Comment: This solution worked for me . https://stackoverflow.com/a/54644331/5033303

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I opened the "Gradle projects" pane on the right, alt-clicked the project, then "refresh Gradle project" and all was fixed.

Comment: this is a better answer than the one i wrote a couple years ago.

Comment: I will sing your praises all day long. You genius, you.

Comment: Same works with 'Reimport Maven Projects' too. Thanks !

Answer (score 31):

Got it....I just imported the project like it didnt already exist and it fixed itself.

Answer (score 3):

This might help too if you have not save the project.

Just copy and paste **app.iml** file from any project inside **app** folder of your project(if you already have saved the project then copy from that) and then restart the project.

This will help, msg me if problem occurs.

Answer (score 2):

For me, I tried just before on my new system with fresh Android Studio install. So I have tried in some different way and worked.

I have copied app.imp file from some other project and added in app folder of the Project. After this I have followed like File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart. It refreshed the file automatically as per the gradle file details and project Run perfectly.

Comment: `File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart` worked for me without my even creating a `.iml` file.

Answer (score 0):

One of the simplest solution I found is that, if your project is synced with git repo (push to git if it is not) then simply delete it from the local system & **re-clone** it. After **reimporting**, it will work like a charm