# Error loading project in Android Studio: cannot load modules

Tags: android, android-studio

When I Checkout a project form Google Cloud, Android Studio sais: "2 modules cannot be loaded. You can remove them from the project" and I cannot see the project. The error is in the iml files app.iml and ProjectName.iml.

Thanks!

Comment: you can't see the code? but if you checkout you have to see it no?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Delete the *.iml files and rebuild the project (Build > Rebuild), it should be ok after that.

Comment: Android Studio automatically suggested this Solution ! +1

Comment: ...ok, fine, but what is the solution to not get these warnings?

Comment: @turingtested these files are generated from the IDE and sometimes they are out of sync (i.e. you remane a module, you change dependencies). But I haven't seen this problem for a while with the newer version of android studio. I don't really have a solution since this problem was easily to fix when you rebuild the project.

Comment: Exit Android Studio, delete *.iml and .idea directory and re-import. Works for me.

Comment: wow!!.. that's work for me. if I add what I did additionally, I import the project as a new one. Not from the recent project. I removed the project from the recent list.

Comment: deleting .idea directory and then opening the project works for me.

Answer (score 29):

The best way to get rid of this problem is below:

1- close the project

2- close Android Studio IDE

3- delete the .idea directory

4- delete all .iml files

5- open Android Studio IDE and import the project again

Comment: This suggestion works for me.

Answer (score 8):

As was already answered here the best solution is deleting all .iml files, but it could be done just Refreshing Gradle Project at Gradle tab> right click on your project > Refresh Gradle Project.

Then a Clean and Rebuild should be done also.

**Edit:**

The screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

I think you can take the IDE automatic advice of deleting the xxx.iml files

Comment: I did and it worked. Initially I thought the advice will make things worse but that is far from the truth

Answer (score 7):

Removing `modules.xml` file under the `/.idea` folder solved my issue.

Comment: underrated fixed my flutter heirarchy thanks

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue in Android Studio 3.4 when I loaded an old project. I found some XML files in the `.idea` folder, including the file `.idea/modules.xml`.

It contained multiple `<module fileurl="...">` tags, some of these were duplicates of existing modules but these had incorrect paths, in the fileurl attribute. I closed the project, deleted these duplicate tags, and reopened the project. This resolved the error for me.

Answer (score 1):

For my Flutter project, it was not enough to delete the .idea directory in the project root, I had to delete also .idea folder in android directory.

1- close the project

2- close Android Studio IDE

3- delete the .idea directory, but also **android/.idea** directory!

4- delete all .iml files

5- open Android Studio IDE and reopen project

That's it, happy coding.